# Android - onclick with ternary operator using databinding

Tags: android

i am using databinding in my app. I need to call a method from onclick based on condition. Both method is present in different viewmodel.

```
<layout>
<data>
<variable name ="v1"
          type ="ViewModel1"/>
<variable name ="v2"
          type ="ViewModel2"/>
</data>

<TextView
   android:onclick ="@{()-> true ? V1.foo() : v2.foo()}"/>
</layout>
```

I tried like above method but not successful. Can anyone help me.

Comment: It will be better if you can post your view model codes here too..

Comment: You need write `v1.foo()` instead of `V1.foo()`

Comment: instead of true use the condition and change V1 tov1